# How to add bootstrap modal with link_to so the link content open in modal ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap modal http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals on a rails link to open that link in the modal

```
<%= link_to page_path, target: '_blank' %>
```

but somehow it is not working. The standard toggle code is -

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn">Launch demo modal</a>
```

but I am not sure how to apply it to link_to in rails, any help ?

Thanks

Comment: I made this work by adding requirements to my application.js in this order:
//= require popper, //= require turbolinks, //= require bootstrap
You can check out the example here: https://kolosek.com/rails-creating-modals

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Below is the code if you want to preload the modal on the page in hidden state

```
<%= link_to "Open modal", "#my-modal", :class => "btn", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="my-modal" title="My modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal Body
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to load the modal through ajax then you can do something like this

```
<%= link_to "Open modal", new_post_path, :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "my-modal" %>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="my-modal" title="My modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">New Post</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body a-unique-class">
    New Post Body
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `posts/new.js.erb` you would include

```
$(".a-unique-class").html('<%= j render "posts/_form" %>')
```

Make sure that you have a *unique* id or class for every modal body.

Assuming you want to create a new post using modal form, the controller code and `_form.html.erb` is in place

Comment: Thanks benchwarmer, though it didn't worked. Here is my code <%= link_to "Open modal", page_path, :class => "btn", "data-toggle" => "modal" %> but it still opening the page in new tab

Comment: You want to preload the modal on same page or want to have modal's body loaded through ajax?

Comment: I am fine with anything, do note that on that page, there can be 5-6 such inks so I am not sure having 5-6 modals preloaded is a good idea

Comment: I know this post is old, but just a small sintax correction in the code:

$(".a-unique-class").html('<%= j render "posts/_form" %> ')

Comment: why does this just load the string '<%= j render  "posts/_form" %>' into the modal body for me? Is there a config setting I'm missing to let javascript through?

Comment: Ahh, because I was putting the the posts/new.js.erb file in the assets/javascripts folder. I moved it to the appropriate views folder and it works like a charm.

Comment: Hi guys, I am not really sure where is the `file.js.erb`located. Can anyone tell me? Or I need to create that file?
Note: my rails version 4.2.6

Comment: You need to create it in your views/posts folder

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `<%= link_to "Open modal", new_post_path, :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#my-modal" %>` so that the data-target is an unique id? However this solution doesn't seem to work for bootstrap3. You should use the html code in the examples here: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: And in the `posts/new.js.erb` it should be `$(".a-unique-class").html('<%= j render "form" %>')`. Then everything will work :).

Answer (score 18):

There is a prettier way to add `data` attributes in Rails. You can do something like this to get the same results.

```
<%= link_to 'Click Here', "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#modal"} %>
```

Comment: What's the best way to just load the action view instead of the whole page?  this example seems to load the application view and the link_to page.  What if I just wanted the edit.html.erb view and nothing else?  thanks!

Comment: I recently did something similar to this where my index action view had several records. Each record has an associated modal with tabs. Each tab rendered a lot of data. Instead of polluting the browser with a bunch of data that may never be seen on that view, I loaded it on demand. Check out the Railscast source code to see how Ryan does it. You can tailor it to your likings. Took what would have been a 500KB footprint down to an initial 15KB.

Comment: The Railscasts. :) It wasn't a particular episode, but rather the actual Railscasts site. https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts

Answer (score -2):

There is a syntax error in benchwarmer's answer above.

try this instead:

```
$(".a-unique-class").html('<%= j render "posts/form" %>')
```

Comment: this should ideally be a comment. also this is just part of an accepted answer so you shouldn't post such answers. you could optionally edit the answer (_but all this is possible only after gaining some reputation_). read [answer]