# link_to with embedded ruby in the data-toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152486/how-to-add-bootstrap-modal-with-link-to-so-the-link-content-open-in-modal) SE question to put a form in a bootstrap modal with rails. 
The person who answered the question states: "Make sure that you have a unique id or class for every modal body.".  So I am trying to put a unique id number in my link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post.id), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "<%= post.id %>-my-modal" %>
```

But this is causing an error.  If I take out <%= post.id %> I do not have an error, but the modal behavior does not work.

How can I add the post.id with embedded ruby to the link to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post.id), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#{post.id}-my-modal" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you open a <% ... %> tag, you are writing ruby code. What this means is that you can't nest <% ... %> tags inside another <% ... %> tag because these tags aren't ruby syntax.

Inside the tag, to do string interpolation, use normal ruby methods:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post.id), :class => "btn", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#{post.id}-my-modal" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only mistake is putting another (ruby) tag <% %> inside the same tag.

In **erb** (embedded ruby) one **<%= %> tag** cannot have another tag inside.

This code result a syntax error.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", .... "data-target" => "<%= post.id %>-my-modal" %>
```

If you plan to **output/render** data inside the tag and quoted as string,
used ***#{put_data_hare}***

Output like:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", .... "data-target" => "#{post.id}-my-modal" %>
```

In other case, you can do like:

```
post.id.to_s + "-my-modal"
```