# bootstrap modal dissappearing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with a bootstrap modal in rails 4. I'm trying to display a modal when you click an image. And actually the modal is displayed, but only for a few seconds, and then it close itself. 
(I'm using bootstrap-sass gem)

This is the code I have:

```
<%= link_to image_tag (destacado.imagen.small), data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"} %>


            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong??  Thank you in advance for any help!
Peyu

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152486/how-to-add-bootstrap-modal-with-link-to-so-the-link-content-open-in-modal

Comment: I've already tryied that, and works fine for simple link, but it doesn't work for image clicking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your `link_to` will redirect the page.

Not a lot of information is provided, so that's just my guess.

If you wanted your link to just do `data-toggle` behaviour, maybe it doesn't need to be a link, just an `image_tag` with `data-toggle` behaviour.